# check the type of variable passed in a subroutine in perl

Tags: perl, subroutine

I want to get the type of variable passed to the subroutine.While googling I came across the under-below solution, but this is not giving satisfactory results .
My problem is illustrated in the below example

```
    sample("test");
    sample(\%a);

    sub sample {
      my ($argv1) = @_;
      if(ref($argv1) eq "STRING") {
        print "string\n";
      }
      elsif(ref($argv1) eq "HASH") {
        print "HASH\n";
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) never produces "STRING".  (Well, unless you create a `STRING` class and bless an object into it.)  A normal string is not a reference, so `ref` returns a false value:

```
sample("test");
sample(\%a);

sub sample {
  my ($argv1) = @_;
  if(not ref($argv1)) {
    print "string\n";
  }
  elsif(ref($argv1) eq "HASH") {
    print "HASH\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: @mob, yes, that's an example of blessing an object into the `STRING` class, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

So don't google, then. Read the official documentation instead.

[ref](http://p3rl.org/ref) returns the empty string for scalars.